# Open MPI "Hello, World!" is not compiling

Tags: c++, g++, mpi

Here is a simple MPI "Hello, World!" program.

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int size, rank;
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   printf("SIZE = %d RANK = %d\n",size,rank);
   MPI_Finalize();   
   return(0);
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to compile:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
MPI::Datatype::Free()               /var/tmp//ccE6aG2w.o
MPI::Win::Free()                    /var/tmp//ccE6aG2w.o
MPI::Comm::Comm()                   /var/tmp//ccE6aG2w.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to main
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've googled a lot, viewed mailing lists, thousands of them. They say `libmpi_cxx` is not linking. But it's in the compiler flags.

Here is `--showme` data:

```
mpic++ --showme:compile
-I/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/include -I/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/include/openmpi

mpic++ --showme:link
-R/opt/mx/lib -R/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/lib -L/usr/openmpi/ompi-1.5/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lnsl -lrt -lm -ldl -lsocket -lmpi_cxx
```

My compiler is g++.

Comment: Are you properly linking the (correct) library?

Comment: @MarkGarcia what do you mean after proper linking?

Comment: Could you show us the complete command line(s) you use to compile and link this code? As written, your code should be able to compile and link with `mpicc`, since it makes no reference to the C++ bindings.

Comment: I think its an environment variable problem

Answer (score 13):

Just place the **mpi.h** header file above all header files
sometimes that causes problem to compile

I am not sure how u execute your code.
Compiling

```
mpic++ your_code_file.c
```

Execution

```
mpirun -np <no. of Processors> ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. Note that Open MPI 1.5 is ancient.  Please upgrade to the latest version in the Open MPI 1.6.x series (which is currently 1.6.3, but note that the [www.open-mpi.org](http://www.open-mpi.org) web site is currently undergoing a planned year-end maintenance and won't be back up until later today, Thursday, December 28, 2012).
2. I'm curious: why are you compiling a C program with mpic++?  You only need to use mpicc -- the C MPI wrapper compiler.  That would definitely avoid your issue.  However, if you are using this small C hello world program as a simple example and your actual target is to compile a C++ MPI program, then mpic++ is the correct wrapper to try (even with a simple C program).  If that's the case, then you have some kind of incompatibility / misconfiguration between your C++ compiler and the C++ compiler that Open MPI was compiled/installed with.
3. Looking at your mpic++ --showme output, it looks like you have some kind of package distribution of Open MPI -- -R is not put in the flags by default, for example.  Where did you get this Open MPI installation?  It's quite possible that it is not (fully) compatible with your g++ installation (e.g., if it was compiled with a different version of g++).
4. That being said, your mpic++ --showme output is also weird in that it lists -lmpi_cxx at the *end* of the line.  It should be to the *left* of -lmpi, not to the *right* of it.  I'm not sure how your installation got borked like that, but that is another possible cause.

So to sum up, my answer is:

1. Please try upgrading Open MPI and see if the problem goes away.
2. Double check that your installation of Open MPI is compatible with your system.

Comment: I had this problem long ago and it wasn’t the case now, but I want to answer on (3). `Where did you get this Open MPI installation?` I use Mac OS X and I try to avoid manual configuring and installing software. So I used MacPorts to install OpenMPI library (as well as gcc/g++). It seems that it can cause problems, so maybe it’s a good decision to install OpenMPI manually (at least for late 2012). Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is a also much easer and more flexible to compile openmpi and mpi programs in a  "Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers" IDE.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-parallel-application-developers/junosr1

Comment: The point was to use openmpi on remote server without even `sudo` rights. But thanks a lot for a link, maybe I could use this IDE on my Mac Mini due to problems with MacPorts.